# I cannot show a file-upload button

Tags: python, html, django

I cannot show a file-upload button.
I wrote in profile.html like

```
{% extends "registration/accounts/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
user.username: {{ user.username }}<hr>
user.is_staff: {{ user.is_staff }}<hr>
user.is_active: {{ user.is_active }}<hr>
user.last_login: {{ user.last_login }}<hr>
user.date_joined: {{ user.date_joined }}
{% endblock %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>UPLOAD</title>


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  <form action="{% url 'accounts:upload_save' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ p_id }}" name="p_id">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}

   <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

So,I wrote multipart/form-data tag like

```
 <form action="{% url 'accounts:upload_save' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">.
```

But, profile.html did not show the part of   ~ .

it showed only {% extends "registration/accounts/base.html" %}
~ {% endblock %}.

How can i fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by upper and lower? Plus good thing would be to show base.html as well

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar thx,ur comments.I added my code info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing and position of **{% block content %}** is wrong in your code.
There are several issues with your code and I removed them.
You dont need an extra **{% block body %}**.
So you should use this code instead :

```
  {% extends "registration/accounts/base.html" %}
  {% block content %}

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html lang="ja">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>UPLOAD</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    user.username: {{ user.username }}<hr>
    user.is_staff: {{ user.is_staff }}<hr>
    user.is_active: {{ user.is_active }}<hr>
    user.last_login: {{ user.last_login }}<hr>
    user.date_joined: {{ user.date_joined }}

    <div class="container">
      <form action="{% url 'accounts:upload_save' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ p_id }}" name="p_id">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>

  {% endblock %}
```

Also Note that, Place the csrf_token in correct position and add **value="Upload"** to **input type="submit"** .